# Create an instance of an ASMX stub object from a real object

Tags: c#, proxy, asmx, stub, instantiation

I have an ASMX web service that exposes several objects.  I have a real instance of that object, and I would like to instantiate a stub object that is populated from it. Clearly there is such functionality already, because when the web service returns a value it is creating the stub and populating it. I just need to do the same thing manually.

Ideas?

Comment: I answered a similar question at the following link: [The following link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408687/asmx-object-proxy-object-conversion/1408875#1408875)

Answer (score 0):

You said

> the web service returns a value it is creating the stub and populating it

This is not true. The web service uses the XML Serializer to serialize the object into a SOAP message, then sends it to the client. At the client side, the SOAP is deserialized back into an object, though this time, it's a proxy object.